# Is it ok to make a ract native app only in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So... I just started to learn React Native to create an android app, and I am a little confused, should I only use java script for the visual part with react and the rest of the app with java ?
Or can I make the whole app with javascript and some Node modules ?

Comment: You write JavaScript code code, and it works with the native operating system components, for which you are developing

Answer (score 0):

You can write everything in Javascript for Android and iOS. That's the purpose of react-native. See an Android code example here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969

But you can also mix in native Android Java classes and then import then call them in your JS code. This is useful if you want to use components which are currently not yet implemented in react-native. Check out this example to read more about using native components: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html